# Determine the formatting of a word from in a Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I am writing an application in C# that uses the Microsoft Office interop DLL to read a Word document.  This is working fine.

I'd now like to also determine the formatting applied to the words I'm reading--for example, check if it's bold or italic or underlined.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Bold**, **Italic** or **Underline** properties of the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range** object.

This is an example of code:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        string fileName = @"C:\folder\document.docx";
        Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = wordDoc.Range();
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range word in rng.Words)
        {
            if (word.Bold == -1)
            {
                //Do wathever you want with the bold text                    
            }
            else if (word.Italic == -1)
            {
                //Do wathever you want with the italic text
            }
            else if ( ((WdUnderline) word.Underline) == WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle)
            {
                //Do wathever you want with the underline text
            }
        }

        wordApp.Documents.Close();
        wordApp.Quit();
```

Note that the properties word.Bold and word.Italic don't return TRUE or FALSE, but an integer that represents one of three possible states. From MSDN:

> This property returns True, False or wdUndefined (a mixture of True and False).

The value -1 corresponds to TRUE in these cases.
Otherwise the word.Underline property is an enumeration and you can find all the possible values here: [WdUnderline enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdunderline.aspx)